# When proxying an array, and accessing the map function, why is the array's constructor checked?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a proxy of an array, and then calling `.map` on the proxy to iteratively retrieve the elements in the target array:

```
const proxiedArray = new Proxy([...], {
    get: function(target, prop) {
      console.log(target, prop) // This is just to see what properties I'm retrieving
      return target[prop]
    }
})

proxiedArray.map(el => ...)
```

Surprisingly, The log is:

```
[...] "map"
[...] "length"
[...] "constructor"
[...] "0"
[...] "1"
[...] "2"
[...] "3",
etc
```

I saw on [this post](https://2ality.com/2016/11/proxying-builtins.html) that arrays can be 'wrapped transparently', which I assume is why `.map` works. But I see that then the proxy is asked for 3 properties: `map`, `length`, and `constructor`.

Why is this? (in particular, why is the constructor checked?)

Comment: I think `proxiedArray.__proto__` will be `Array` so it will have the same methods?

Comment: why would the proxied array be linked to the Array constructor?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? The target is an Array. Just to confirm: `Object.getPrototypeOf(proxiedArray) // Array []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `proxiedArray.map`, you are accessing the `"map"` property from the object. This is why, that property gets logged first.

---

If you check the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) of `Array.prototype.map`, there is this code:

```
var len = O.length >>> 0
```

which is accessing current array's length. So, that explains the `length` property.

---

I'm not sure about the `constructor` property. I copied the polyfill of `Array.prototype.map`, added `debugger` inside it and executed your code. The `constructor` property was not logged.

It is probably coming from this bit `A = new Array(len)`. Internally, javascript might be handling this part a bit differently than what the polyfill suggests (Something like `A = new this.constrcutor(len)` will access the constructor property)

```js
Array.prototype.map = function(callback /*, thisArg*/ ) {

  var T, A, k;

  if (this == null) {
    throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
  }

  // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
  //    value as the argument.
  var O = Object(this);

  // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
  //    method of O with the argument "length".
  // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
  var len = O.length >>> 0;

  // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
  // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
  }

  // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    T = arguments[1];
  }

  // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
  //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
  //    len is the value of len.
  A = new Array(len);

  // 7. Let k be 0
  k = 0;

  // 8. Repeat, while k < len
  while (k < len) {

    var kValue, mappedValue;

    // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
    //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
    // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
    //    method of O with argument Pk.
    //   This step can be combined with c
    // c. If kPresent is true, then
    if (k in O) {

      // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      kValue = O[k];

      // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
      //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
      //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
      mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

      // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
      // Pk, Property Descriptor
      // { Value: mappedValue,
      //   Writable: true,
      //   Enumerable: true,
      //   Configurable: true },
      // and false.

      // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
      // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
      //   value: mappedValue,
      //   writable: true,
      //   enumerable: true,
      //   configurable: true
      // });

      // For best browser support, use the following:
      A[k] = mappedValue;
    }
    // d. Increase k by 1.
    k++;
  }

  // 9. return A
  return A;
};

const proxiedArray = new Proxy([1, 2, 3], {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    console.log(prop) // This is just to see what properties I'm retrieving
    return target[prop]
  }
})

proxiedArray.map(el => el)
```

Comment: I think that `new SomeFunction` results in the constructor property being set on the target object - I remember reading that somewhere. So this answer makes perfect sense. Thanks